# Need to repair MBR without using CD

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I just reinstalled Windows 7 on my PC which erased my Master Boot Record and I can't boot into my Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin partition. The computer in question is an ultrabook, so I don't have a CD drive to boot from. Is there a way to repair the MBR from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a usb thumb drive, you can use penndrivelinux from windows to make it bootable with an applicable distribution.  From there you can fix it using boot-repair.

Please see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/